# Python - JSON array to DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have this following `JSON` array.

```
[
    {
        "foo"=1
    },
    {
        "foo"=2
    },
    ...
]
```

I would like to convert it to `DataFrame` object using `pd.read_json()` command like below.

```
df = pd.read_json(my_json) #my_json is JSON array above
```

However, I got the error, since `my_json` is a `list`/`array` of `json`. The error is `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>`.

Besides iterating through the `list`, is there any efficient way to extract/convert the `JSON` to `DataFrame` object?

Comment: You're calling `read_csv` on a list, in your example.

Comment: @AmiTavory @thebjorn typo guys. Edited to the correct one, i.e. `read_json()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `df = pd.DataFrame(YourList)`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = [
    {
        "foo":1
    },
    {
        "foo":2
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   foo
0    1
1    2
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems in your question:

1. It called `to_csv` on a list.
2. The JSON was illegal, as it contained `=` signs instead of `:`

This works by me:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.DataFrame(json.loads("""[
    {
        "foo": 1
    },
    {
        "foo": 2
    }
]"""))

   foo
0    1
1    2
```

You can also call `read_json` directly.